# Trying to debug NullPointerException when using ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> getStudentClasses(Student student, ArrayList<Integer>[] classesXstudents) {
      ArrayList<Integer> classes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      for (int i = 0; i < classesXstudents.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < classesXstudents[i].size(); j++) {
          if (classesXstudents[i].get(j) == student.getID()) {
            classes.add(i+1);
          }
        }
      }
      return classes;
  }
```

throws `NullPointerException` at the line

```
  for (int j = 0; j < classesXstudents[i].size(); j++) {
```

which I'm assuming means `classesXstudents[i].size()` is `null` at some point. `classesXstudents` is an array of `ArrayList` objects. How should I debug this case?

Comment: classesXstudents: was empty try to add date in it

Comment: Did you try to put a break point at line that calls to your method and see what `classesXstudents` contains?

Comment: By the way, using array of collection is not a good idea

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this.

```
if (classesXstudents[i] != null){
   for (int j = 0; j < classesXstudents[i].size(); j++) {
       //....
   }
} else {
   //
}
```

Some of your elements are probably null, you should probably check where they're initialized. It might just be that you forgot to initialize one of them.

Comment: I tried that and it won't compile it says Generate.java:118: error: incomparable types: int and <null>
        if (classesXstudents[i].size() != null) {

Comment: never mind it works :P thanks

Comment: Don't compare the size. Look again, I don't compare size, but the array itself. Ints can't be null in java. Only reference types.

Comment: Oh okay, great. If this answers your question please upvote and accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

What that means is that some element of the `classesXstudents[i]` array is null.

Look at how that array is filled. Search for cases where null might be inserted, or when some element might be left unassigned (default value is null), perhaps at the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because **some elements of your `ArrayList<Integer> classesXstudents[i]` are `null`**.

You can fix this problem by checking if the element whose `size` you are asking for actually isn't `null`.

```
 if (classesXstudents[i] != null) {
      // Your for-loops and rest of the code here
 }
```

Adding the above snippet will check to see if the element is `null` (say you forgot to initialize it) or not. You can incorporate this in your code as follows:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> getStudentClasses(Student student, ArrayList<Integer>[] classesXstudents) 
{
    ArrayList<Integer> classes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < classesXstudents.length; i++) {
        if (classesXstudents[i] != null) // This statement is what you need to add

            for (int j = 0; j < classesXstudents[i].size(); j++) {
                if (classesXstudents[i].get(j) == student.getID()) {
                    classes.add(i+1);
                }
            }
   }
   return classes;
}
```